# Using an array formula in Excel with sumif

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs

I'm trying to make an array formula work to sum data based on vertical and horizontal criteria in Excel. Here is the formula I've tried, but it's returning a #NAME? error.

=arrayformula(SUM(IF('By day'!$C$3:$GB$3='By week'!C$1,IF('By day'!$B$4:$B$395='By week'!$A3,'By day'!$C$4:$GB$395))))

Can anyone suggest what I need to change to make this work? I'm new to array formulas so any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried just pressing Enter and pressing Ctrl + Enter, and neither worked.

I also tried this, which is correctly summing based on the vertical range ('By day'!$B$4:$B$395) but doesn't take account of the horizontal range ('By day'!$C$3:$GB$3) - i.e. it simply sums all columns that match the vertical range:

=SUM(IF(('By day'!B4:B401='By week'!A3)+('By day'!C3:GB3='By week'!B1),'By day'!C4:GB235,0))

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `arrayformula` is not a thing in Excel.   ( it is in google sheets)

Comment: Why not you are using `SUMIFS()` function.

Comment: Harun, I thought SUMIFS() can't handle vertical and horizontal criteria simultaneously?

Comment: @user14704685 Then you need just two `SUMISF()` like `SUMISF(...) + SUMIFS(...)`

Comment: @Harun24HR - thank you. I didn't realise that was possible. I have tried this but I couldn't get it to work with SUMIFS(). I have got something working with SUMIF():

=SUMIF('By day'!$B$4:$B$150,'By week'!$A3,'By day'!$C$4:$GB$150) + SUMIF('By day'!$C$3:$GB$3,AND(">="&'By week'!D$1,"<="&'By week'!D$1+6),'By day'!$C$4:$GB$150)

However, this is not returning the correct data. On some lines it returns zero (incorrectly). On other lines it returns the total for the source data row, not filtered by column. Thanks in advance for any further suggestions - sorry if I'm being dense!